# convert amp; to & and ?F to Degree F in Vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

The XML String I am getting from other application is converting `&` to `&amp;` and `0F` to `?F` etc.

I am loading the XML string into XDocument and inserting into db using linq.

Is there any easy way to replace those characters with actual ones.

thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking: encoding those characters as entities is the _correct_ way to handle that, and the XDocument class should be decoding those entities for you.  Can you show some more code?

Comment: When I load the XMLstring into xmlDocument
Dim sr As New StringReader(data)
Dim violations As XDocument = XDocument.Load(sr)

°F is getting converted to ?F
°C is getting converted into ?C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The escape code for the degrees symbol is &#176;

Are you able to replace the ° symbols with that text instead?